# How do I pass info to route values so I can redirect back after I login Asp.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, html.actionlink, routevalues

Here is my actionlink to my login page with route values as null, so now my controllers Login action gets a returnUrl value of null

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Log in", "Login", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "loginLink" })</li>
```

If I'm on my search page where the URL has parameters like this

> www.mypage.com/home/search&city=san+francisco&ClassDate=08%2F25%2F2015

and then I click on the login link what gets put into the route values so that I can get back to this page with these parameters? Will the page reload when I go back after I login?

Here is the controller action.

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
{
    ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick and dirty option:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Log in", "Login", "Account", new { returnUrl =  Request.RawUrl }, new { id = "loginLink" })
```

Best practice though, would be to add the `ReturnUrl` to a model, and pass that to the view:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Log in", "Login", "Account", new { returnUrl = Model.ReturnUrl }, new { id = "loginLink" })
```